# Count unique values in a row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, row, unique

The test data:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 3)], ['c1', 'c2'])
df.show()
#+---+---+
#| c1| c2|
#+---+---+
#|  1|  1|
#|  2|  3|
#|  3|  3|
#+---+---+
```

I intend to count distinct values in every **row**, creating a separate column with the count. How to do it?

The desired result:

```
#+---+---+---+
#| c1| c2| c3|
#+---+---+---+
#|  1|  1|  1|
#|  2|  3|  2|
#|  3|  3|  1|
#+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the size of `array_distinct`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('c3', F.size(F.array_distinct(F.array(*df.columns)))).show()
+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|
|  2|  3|  2|
|  3|  3|  1|
+---+---+---+
```